# ASP.NET Data Caching and how to invalidate

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

My web application is using the asp.net cache object to store data from the database. I am looking for an elegant to invalidate cache objects but haven't come up with anything elegant yet.

It is easy to invalidate a single record or a list of all records in a single table, by keeping track of their cache keys. However I may have any number of lists of subsets of a table's data. I would like to invalidate only the cache records of the lists that contain a particular record, when that record changes. I don't want to have to invalidate all the lists of data for that table if only one of the lists contain that record.

I have tried SqlDependency and not happy with it as I've run into a lot of issues. Do you have any idea how to attack this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: just wondering, what is your invalidation criteria? by time or you check the DB against for last update etc?

Comment: if you are using EF by chance you can use this - http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers - which is a wrapper for you data context and handles caching automatically for you

Comment: @rushonerok, right now I am using Linq to SQL, not entity framework, but this looks very cool, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @winfred, I can invalidate anytime an update is made to a record, since all the changes will be made in the same application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a static `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

the key will use a naming scheme like table_primarykey which represents a single record

the value is a list of cache key names that the record is cached in

this will let you effectively find what records are cached where, permitting that you manage the dictionary while adding and removing items (use a callback) from the cache.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and nice idea! It is not as elegant of a solution I had hoped for because I will still have to extract the list of primary keys for each record I am caching, but for my purposes it should work well.